# System.Decimal OverflowException - Handle large numeric datatypes

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

We have a lot of queries in our system that have calculations where the result of the calculations may exceed the limit of System.Decimal. This returns a error from the NPGSQL .NET driver.

Consider this small example :

```
-- Column : Price numeric(19,5)
-- Column : Discount numeric(29,15)
-- Column : ExchangeRate numeric(29,20)

-- Price = 119.91237
-- Discount = 10%
-- ExhangeRate = 2.581236

-- So Total = Price * Discount * ExchangeRate
SELECT 
    119.91237::numeric(19,5) * 
    0.10::numeric(29,15) * 
    2.581236::numeric(29,20)
```

If we try to read this value in our application with a reader :

```
var value = reader.GetValue(0);
```

Returns this error :

```
System.OverflowException: Numeric value does not fit in a System.Decimal
NumericHandler.Read(NpgsqlReadBuffer buf, Int32 len, Boolean async, FieldDescription fieldDescription)
NpgsqlTypeHandler.Read[TAny](NpgsqlReadBuffer buf, Int32 len, Boolean async, FieldDescription fieldDescription)
NpgsqlTypeHandler`1.ReadAsObject(NpgsqlReadBuffer buf, Int32 len, Boolean async, FieldDescription fieldDescription)
NpgsqlTypeHandler.ReadAsObject(NpgsqlReadBuffer buf, Int32 len, FieldDescription fieldDescription)
NpgsqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 ordinal)
```

Cast option - One option is to cast the result of this query into a smaller numeric value that fits the System.Decimal. But given all of our queries this will be a lot of work, and hard to find all these places in our current code base.

String option - Another option is to threat all results of type numeric as a string, then truncate the string in order to later represent it as a System.Decimal. This will basically result in more work than the cast option.

Is there any way we can approach this in a different way?

Comment: That's an [active Npgsql bug](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/4299). BTW why are the fields so large? For one thing, exchange rates are never published with 20 decimals. They're published using an exact number of digits specified by regulations The other fields are suspiciously large too - in low-value currencies that require lots of integral digits, you don't get a lot of *decimals*.

Comment: @Andomar the problem isn't Decimal, those numbers don't have so many digits. It's the way Npgsql tries to load them. There's an open bug about this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ah you're right, it's tagged postgres too. I'll remove the comment.

Comment: You should inspect the database and fix fields with such unusual values. They actually cause problems, by taking additional space or worse, by producing incorrect results. When accounting/finance rules specify a maximum number of decimals and rounding, using *more* may seem more accurate but results in incorrect results. With irrational numbers like `1.33333333.....` no number of digits will fix the inevitable rounding

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for the input. Even when limiting the columns to for instance 2.581239::numeric(19,6) we can still get these issues in calculations. Just by calculating with 5 columns we can get overflow of the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You could truncate the result of your query before reading it in the DB,  with the `TRUNC()` function. [TRUNC specs](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-math-functions/postgresql-trunc/)

I have never used it before so i can't make any statements about performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this would still mean that we need to go through all of our queries and look for the potential calculations where this might happen. (same as for the cast option).

Comment: Link to the official PostgreSQL documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html